# Is it possible to pass data from middleware to the request in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

I have a custom api auth based on `api_key` via request header. It is implemented using a middleware. I'd like to attach the authenticated in user to the request, so it will be available in the api controllers.

Here's what I tried in my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Load api key
    $api_key = ApiKey::where('api_key', $request->header('X-API-KEY'))
        ->with('user')
        ->first();

    // Check if api key is valid
    if (!$api_key) {
        throw new HttpException(401, 'Invalid api key.');
    }


    // Append api key user to the request
    $request->attributes->add(['api_user' => $api_key->user]);

    // Proceed with the request
    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in my controller, I've tried to retrieve the custom request attribute like this:

```
var_dump($request->get('api_user')); // returns 'null'
var_dump($request->attributes->get('api_user')); // returns 'null'
var_dump($request->api_user); // returns 'null'
```

I've also tried setting the api user to request like this also:

```
$request->attributes->set('api_user', $api_key->user);
$request->merge(['api_user' => $api_key->user]);
```

Still no luck.

Any ideas? or is this not possible?

Comment: `$request->merge(['api_user' => $api_key->user]);` should work, I do this when refreshing access tokens.

Comment: I was trying to load it inside the constructor, it doesn't work in there. It has to be inside a method in a controller, then it's fine.

Comment: Try this : `request()->merge(['api_user', $api_key->user]);` and accesss it using `$request->input('api_user')`

Comment: Using the method you mentioned, will I be able to access the `api_user` from the controller constructor?

Comment: Ah didn't see your last comment. I don't think so, at least, I've never tried. I always do it within the handle method.

Comment: You controller constructor doesn't have access to the `Request` class because your controller constructor isn't called on every `request`, so no, you can't access that value inside of your controller constructor

Comment: That's what I thought. When I used the `$request->merge()` and moved the accessor outside of the constructor, it's working fine now :)